# Printing on Printronix T5000r over ethernet using Java

Tags: java, printing, label

I have a problem with printing on this specific printer.

```
public void print(String fileName, String printerIp) {

 try {
  BufferedReader streamIn  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
  String line;

   Socket socket = new Socket(printerIp, 9100);
   Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

   while ((line = streamIn.readLine()) != null) {
    writer.write(line);
   }
   writer.flush();
  socket.close();
  streamIn.close();

}
```

The situation looks like everything is fine but the printer do not print, when I use other program to print everything works fine. 
Any thoughts ?

Comment: Are you using the correct protocol? What you have here looks like you take a file and dump it to the printer directly - I think you need to use the appropriate printing protocol: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetDirect

Comment: Also, this may be of interest: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/printing.fm6.html#1000147

Comment: Regarding printService i think that there is no way to specify printer via IP. Do you have some example for dumping whole file to the printer ?

Comment: @Piskvor You have had right about that whole dump. Thak you.

Comment: You're welcome, but frankly, I'm surprised that it works. Oh well, live and learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to write whole file to the printer.

```
   public void printFile(File file, String printerIp) throws PrintException, IOException {

            Socket socket = new Socket(printerIp, 9100);

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)file.length()];

            fileInputStream.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);

            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

            outputStream.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);

                 //Curious thing is that we have to wait some time to make more prints.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }

            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            socket.close();
            fileInputStream.close();
        }
```